# pointer of int calculate average

Tags: c

i have a problem in the result of the average in the function calcular, not return a correct number, and the rand return values equals, i dont know the reason for the bad average

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int calcular(int * _arreglo, int * _tam);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int tam = 0;
    if (argc == 2) {
        tam = atoi(argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("No se ha ingresado correctamente el tamaño \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int * arreglo;
    arreglo = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * tam);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        arreglo = (int * )(rand() % 101);
        printf("soy %d \n", ((int)(arreglo)));
        arreglo++;
    }
    int promedio = calcular(arreglo, & tam);
    printf("Promedio: %d \n", promedio);
    free(arreglo);
    return 0;
}

int calcular(int * _arreglo, int * _tam) {
    int pro = 0;
    int i;
    _arreglo = _arreglo - ( * _tam);
    for (i = 0; i < * _tam; i++) {
        pro = pro + ((int)(_arreglo));
        _arreglo++;
    }
    return (pro / ( * _tam));
}
```

Comment: Format&indent your code!

Comment: Use `srand` before calling `rand`.

Comment: the principal problem is the average in the function calcular, i think is a problem with the int pointer

Comment: @cad Calling `srand()` is not needed.  That is only useful if code needs to have a _different_ simulation.  Until the first simulation works as intended, _not_ including `srand()`  simplifies debugging.

Answer (score 3):

## Main issues:

1. This:

   ```
   for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
   arreglo=(int *)(rand()%101);
   printf("soy %d \n",((int)(arreglo)));
   arreglo++;
   }
   ```

   doesn't make any sense. You probably wanted

   ```
   for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
       arreglo[i] = (rand() % 101);
       printf("soy %d \n", arreglo[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Here:

   ```
   int calcular(int *_arreglo, int *_tam){
   int pro=0;
   int i;
   _arreglo=_arreglo-(*_tam);
   for(i=0;i<*_tam;i++){
   pro=pro+((int)(_arreglo));
   _arreglo++;
   }
   return (pro/(*_tam));
   }
   ```

   you probably wanted

   ```
   int calcular(int *_arreglo, int *_tam){
       int pro = 0;
       int i;

       for(i = 0; i < *_tam; i++){
           pro = pro + _arreglo[i];
       }

       return (pro / (*_tam));
   }
   ```

## Other issues:

1. You need to call seed `rand` for getting a different set of random values on each run of the program so that you don't get the same set of random numbers on each run of the program. Add `srand(time(NULL));` at the start of `main` after including `time.h`. This will return a different set of random numbers, provided that the program isn't run more than one time in the same second.
2. It doesn't make sense why you are passing `tam` by reference into `calcular`. Pass it by value instead.
3. [There is no need cast the result of `malloc` (and family)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C.
4. Consider checking the return value of `malloc` to see if it was successful. Change:

   ```
   arreglo = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * tam);
   ```

   to

   ```
   if((arreglo = malloc(sizeof(int) * tam)) == NULL) /* If malloc failed */
   {
       fputs("malloc failed; Exiting...", stderr); /* Print the error message in the `stderr` */
       exit(-1); /* Exit the program */
   }
   ```

Comment: `man rand: [...]If no seed value is provided,  the  rand()  function  is  automatically seeded with a value of 1.[...]`.

Comment: But seeding with 1 returns the same values on each run of the program, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy The same seed will always return the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers. That's why that Microsoft card game (I don't remember which one, it's been a very long time) ... asked for a number to play the same game, it is the seed for the generator.

Comment: Sure, but calling `srand(time(0))` causes `rand()` to return the same sequence when the program is run again in the same second.

Comment: @EOF, Exactly. Because of what I say in my previous comment.

Comment: @EOF Edited the answer. I hope it looks OK now.

Comment: Minor: Consider 1) `fputs()` rather than `printf("malloc failed; Exiting...");` for the usual `'%'` concerns. 2)  `fputs(..., stderr)` for error messages.

Comment: @iharob "that Microsoft card game " --> [freecell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeCell)?

Comment: @chux exactly, that one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a serious mistake

```
arreglo = (int *) (rand() % 101);
```

is assigning a random address to the pointer `arreglo`, dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Reassigning the pointer after `malloc()` will cause a memory leak, because now you can't `free()` the pointer returned by `malloc()`. Moreover, you `free()` the pointer with the invalid address assigned with `rand()`, and that is undefined behavior.

---

**Some other considerations**

1. Make your code readable to humans

   - Surround operatrs with white spaces, it adds a lot of clarity to the code because otherwise it becomes difficult to differentiate between *tokens*.
   - Indent your code correctly.
2. You don't need to cast `malloc()`, this also improves readability.
3. Check the pointer returned by `malloc()` for `NULL`, on error `malloc()` returns `NULL`, if you dereference a `NULL` pointer undefined behavior will occur.
4. Use `strtol()` instead of `atoi()` to check for invalid input, like this

   ```
   char *endptr;
   tam = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
   if (*endptr != '\0')
       return -1; /* invalid input */
   ```